# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined thrown when trying to automate following on instagram

Tags: javascript, node.js, instagram, puppeteer

I'm trying to automate getting followers on Instagram using puppeteer but the loop function is not working.

```
let followButtons = await instagram.page.$$('div[role="dialog"] ul li div button');
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

let followButton = followButtons[i];

// Click on the follow button
await followButton.click();

console.log("success4");
await instagram.page.waitFor(4000);
// Wait for the modal to appear
await instagram.page.waitFor('div[id="react-root"]');
await instagram.page.waitFor(1000);
```

}

Error Thrown: `(node:4320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined`

Comment: I got an `error`? what error?

Comment: (node:4320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention the error

Comment: `followButton.click()` in this line -> `followButton` is undefined. Enclose your code in `try catch` block to handle the errors.

Comment: Error Has occured: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at Object.followProcess (C:\Users\Plvtinum\puppe\instagram2.js:77:36)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async C:\Users\Plvtinum\puppe\index2.js:9:5

this is the error I don't know why click is undefined

Comment: `click` is not undefined. The element on which `click` event is applied, is undefined `click of undefined`.

Comment: Before you loop, make sure `followButtons` is an Array of DOM nodes with at least one element in the Array.